# Mapping 'OLD' database to a new database model for use with Symfony FOSUserBundle

Tags: mysql, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I have re-developed a very old site from scratch using Symfony (with FOSUserBundle) and Doctrine. The old site is still online and has 'live' data in the database (which has `latin1` character set) and I trying to work out how to transfer this to the new database (`utf8mb4` character set).

The new site is working well with dummy data that I load into the development database [Doctrine Fixtures](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html). However, for example, with FOSUserBundle the database table has a lot more mandatory parameters with variables such as:

**Current Member:**

```
userid
username
email
password
joindt
```

**FOSUserBundle table:**

```
id
username
username_canonical
email
email_canonical
salt
password
```

However, I've spent the whole weekend trying all different ways to copy the old database and transform it to what is required for the new database, ie exporting from PhpMyadmin with foreign key generation turned off, trying export methods such as:

- 1a. Different configurations of csv files
- 1b. Opening in excel to adjust the columns (eg copying `username` and pasting again as `username_canonical`)
- 1c. Importing the csv file back into PhpMyAdmin as a new database table or removing foreign key constraints and emptying the new table and reading in the data
- 2a. SQL code
- 2b. Running this SQL code to provide the old SQL `INSERT INTO` steps
- 2c. Typing out manual SQL such as `CREATE TABLE Member as SELECT username as username, username as username_canonical FROM old`

I've tried many comibnations of all of these and none have worked. I'm sure if I keep persevering I'll be able to cobble something together to get this FOSUserBundle `Member` table generated. However, I'm concerned that I'll then hit another problem with the associations betwen the tables not letting me create the other tables (eg `Products`, `Orders`).

At a glance:

Comment: I would probably use the [Doctrine\MigrationsBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html) and edit the sql created by running `doctrine:migrations:diff` to handle your changes.  You can write any amount of complex script in them to handle your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have a big problem. In the case of username_canonical and email_canonical is simple because those fields are just username and email without upper letters, maybe others rules apply (you must investigate) but are basically that. The real problem is the password. I assume that in your old database the password is encrypted with some irreversible algorithm. The model of FOSUserBundle is take the registration password , join that with a random generated salt, encrypt the entire set with a defined algorithm, and persist the result. When the login is requested the same process is activated (without salt generation of course).  So, maybe if the old data follow the same steps for registration and authentication you can migrate the old accounts coping the corresponding password and salt field to the new structure, and setting in the new config.yml the same algorithm for encryption, but if the new database need to be in other character set, i don't see a possible migration solution.

If the old password can be retrieved in plaintext, you can managed to generate all the password and salt for the new accounts, if not the case, I don't see a migration way. Maybe if the character set was not necessary, you can change the FOSUserBundle for avoid salt generation (the salt generation prevent dictionary attacks).
There is a possible solution leaving the old database connection only for authentication purpose, and migrate the rest of data, but in addition to manage two connections you have the problem of manually ensure the referential integrity of related tables, but maybe if you have that possibility is the only way of achieve your purpose.

Comment: Hey @abdiel, thanks for pointing that out - I had been wondering about the passwords before and checked my plan under this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34925591/is-there-a-passive-way-to-implement-a-new-hashing-method-for-users-passwords . I think that should protect me from having problems with the password hashs? If I'm missing anything though please do let me know!